# Assign values in new column on condition pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i have a dataframe:

```
id    name    value
 1    asd      0.5
 2    fgg      0.8
 3    hfd      1.5
 4    erw      0.5
```

i have to create a new column `accept` such  that, if the value is greater than 1.0, make `outlier` as 1, else 0.

```
id    name    value   accept
 1    asd      0.5      0
 2    fgg      0.8      0
 3    hfd      1.5      1
 4    erw      0.5      0
```

i can do it using iterrows and use .loc.

```
for index,row in df.iterrows():
    if row['value']>1:
        df.loc[df.index==row.index,'accept'] = 1
    else:
        df.loc[df.index==row.index,'accept'] = 0
```

Is there a simpler way of doing this without iterating?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Condition cast to `int` - `True`s are converted to `1` and `False`s to `0`:

```
df['accept'] = (df['value'] > 1).astype(int)
print (df)
   id name  value  accept
0   1  asd    0.5       0
1   2  fgg    0.8       0
2   3  hfd    1.5       1
3   4  erw    0.5       0
```

For another values use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['accept'] = np.where(df['value'] > 1, 'high', 'low')
print (df)
   id name  value accept
0   1  asd    0.5    low
1   2  fgg    0.8    low
2   3  hfd    1.5   high
3   4  erw    0.5    low
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `np.floor` + `astype(int)` as long as your values are between 0 and 2.

```
df['accept'] = np.floor(df.value).astype(int)
df

   id name  value  accept
0   1  asd    0.5       0
1   2  fgg    0.8       0
2   3  hfd    1.5       1
3   4  erw    0.5       0
```